# Проверка кратности чисел reactjs

Tags: javascript

В JS при проверке кратности возникает баг

Из-за особенностей JS он считает чуть по своему.
20.3 % 0.1 он дает 203, а
20.7 % 0.1 он дает 206.99999999999997

например stepQty = 0.1

и если value = 23.3 - это ок
и если value = 23.33- это не ок

например stepQty = 0.001

и если value = 23.3 - это ок
и если value = 23.33- это не ок

```
if (stepQty) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && (valueQty / stepQty) % 1 === 0
```

тут происходит ошибка, описанная выше.

Каким способом можно фиксануть эти 9?.

```js
let btnIsActive = true;
if (minPrice) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && minPrice < value;

if (maxPrice) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && maxPrice > value;
if (maxQty) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && maxQty > valueQty;
if (minQty) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && minQty < valueQty;
if (minVolume && totalValue)
  btnIsActive = btnIsActive && totalValue > minVolume;
if (maxVolume && totalValue)
  btnIsActive = btnIsActive && totalValue < maxVolume;
if (stepQty) btnIsActive = btnIsActive && (valueQty / stepQty) % 1 === 0;
return btnIsActive;
```

Вариант умножить на 10 и потом разделить

Comment: добавь код как текст, а не картинку

Comment: Странно, документация утверждает, что оператор `%` выполняет целочисленное получение остатка от деления...

Comment: Попробуйте в js, 20.3 % 0.1 = 203, а 20.7 % 0.1 = 206.99999999999997

Comment: @Laskovoebo, непонятно что и где ты пробуешь. Выполнив `20.3 % 0.1` получаю `0.09999999999999959`, поэтому откуда ты взял `203` непонятно. Больше похоже что вместо `%` ты использовал просто `/`

Comment: более того, в коде у тебя вообще нигде нет операции `% 0.1`

Comment: это не баг js, а баг программирования))  щас кто-то переоткроет вопрос, чтобы можно было его закрыть дубликатом на другой %)

Comment: Добавь в вопрос конкретные входные данные и конкретные выходные, сейчас непонятно какие числа куда ты подставляешь и что именно не так с результатом